# Can I insulate portable AC vent duct?

Tags: hvac, insulation

This is a picture of a Gree 8000 btu unit.  Can I put insulation around the vent duct since it is getting a little warm to the touch?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It should not be a burn hazard but adding insulation will only help the performance by reducing the convection of heat from the pipe.

Comment: Conduction. But yes. :)